# Writing pure code without using third-party header files

Tags: c++, c

As  try to learn C/C++, I'm always finding it frustrating that I need to use the header files. It makes it seem like it's not my code, but I am using some other person's code instead. I simply want it to be pure, and be written by myself without using the header files.

I know for certain that C/C++ includes libraries that can give the developer some functions in order to for example create a vector. The Boost library are similar to that, but again, I want to write my own code, and maybe create my own library for my work.

But is this possible? If I wrote my own header files for C/C++ that almost acted like the iostream.h file for example, only that I've made it my own, and optimized it, will it be beneficial for my applications/projects, or should I just use the standard library that is included with the programming languages?

Comment: This is a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: The standard library is the only way to perform input/output in a standard C++ program. You could write a program that doesn't include any library headers, but it would be pretty boring as it would be unable to accept any input or print anything.

Comment: Using other people's code is GOOD. Code reuse is exactly what you want when you are programming, it is an indicator that you are using your time and skills well. Sure you could write everything yourself, but why bother if someone else has done it? Good programmers are lazy, meaning you find the most efficient path possible.

Comment: For special-purpose code that's specific to your projects and needs? Of course. But should you be rewriting general-purpose code with *years*, in fact *decades* of bug-fixes and optimization? That's incredibly unlikely to turn out well. Go use the well-tested building blocks to create something new and interesting.

Comment: It's `iostream`, not `iostream.h`.

Comment: +1: This is a terrible idea, and you're horribly wrong... but that does not make this a bad _question_.

Comment: Imagine you're a developer who is just overwhelmed with work maintaining these libraries, so you go hire another programmer to help.  The new guy comes in and you say, "I need you to write a utility to parse this file."  He says, OK, and fires up his editor and starts `#include <iostream>`.  You quickly say, "No, no, no!  You need to `#include <super_io>` here!  Don't use iostream!"  ... Do you see the problem?

Comment: It is certainly possible. And it may be a good exercise to try and re-implement something that has been done before. It will certainly deepen your understanding. But, more often than not, this is not useful for production code. So be willing to throw whatever you write away.

Comment: Oh, and "C/C++" does not exist.

Comment: The one place where you probably could get away with reimplementing basically everything is embedded software. There are virtually no good C++ libraries for bare metal programming.

Comment: Use another language with modules.  Nobody LIKES header file misery but, with C or C++, you're pretty much stuck with it.

Answer (score 14):

My answer comes, at least partially, in the form of a rhetorical question:

*Are you also going to write your own compiler?*

You're always using something that someone else wrote, and for general-purpose use this is a very, very good thing. Why? Because they are the experts in their field, because they are multiple people, and because their code has gone through decades of rigorous peer review, thorough testing by millions upon millions of people, and many iterations of improved versions.

Shying away from that as an instinct is one thing, but [refusing to use standard headers due to it is *quite* another](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here), especially when you draw the line so arbitrarily<sup>†</sup>.

In short, there is a damned good reason why the C++ standard defines the standard library and why your compiler vendor ships an implementation of it. My strong recommendation is that you work to that principle.

<sub><sup>†</sup> …which is why mine is not a "slippery slope" argument!</sub>

Comment: And invent your own processor, created from your own raw materials with your own hand-made tools, re-derive the necessary laws of physics and mathematics, write all your own operating system, compiler, library, assembler, debugger, etc

Comment: @Puppy: Create new laws of physics and mathematics and construct a new reality from them. It's the only way.

Comment: While the current implementation of physics is quite nice, it clearly has some flaws and hard to find bugs... It really would be for the best if we scrap it and start from scratch. You really are onto something @LightnessRacesinOrbit.

Comment: On a more serious note, writing a compiler is a very nice experience, and deepens ones understanding of how things work. But very few (if anyone individually) would be able to write a compiler that could rival Clang, GCC, MSVC, ICC or similar stable compilers that have years of development and a huge bug-finding user base behind them.

Comment: @Fors: _"writing a compiler is a very nice experience"_ looooool

Comment: @Fors: Only a trivial compiler for a trivial language.

Comment: I struggle with [NIH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) all the time. I'd say it's the primary reason that, despite being an aspiring game developer, I've never developed my own game. Sometimes it's justifiable (I want to learn how to implement these things on my own as a learning exercise), but sometimes you just have to hop onto the giant's shoulders and make some real progress.

Answer (score 4):

Off course you should use the standard library. The only reasons not do so are:

- The class you want does not exist.
- You are a pro C++ programmer and something about its implementation really annoys you.
- You as a beginner want to learn something by trying to build your own simple data storage types (like for instance any vector type )

Your thoughts about "all should be made by yourself" are not that uncommon, but once you've implemented one of the standard types and have spent hours on it while your actual project hasn't progressed one line and when your new "own" type still misses half of the functionality - Then you'll realize that using an existing library (especially the standard library or well known others like boost) might actually be a clever thing.

Comment: *cough* "Class template" *cough*

Comment: I don't like point #2 too much. Implementation details shouldn't be much of a concern to the interface. Not to mention that most classes in the standard library (i.e. containers) allow you to specify some of its internal operations such as allocating.

Comment: @Rapptz: It's not entirely off the mark. One obvious example is the EASTL: EA just didn't have access to a stdlib implementation that could be sufficiently optimised for their use case. This was the perfect opportunity to do "better" for their needs. However, it should be incredibly rare as, more often, if you have a problem with an stdlib implementation, you frakking discuss it with the vendor and get it fixed _there_, not replace the whole thing with your shoddy homemade replacement that's almost certainly orders of magnitude worse in at least every other way.

Comment: @Rapptz: See your point. I meant "implementation" in a broader sense, which is off course a little critical in programming context. Maybe I should have just said "something about it annoys you".

Comment: @bluewater2: Without qualification (e.g. my example above) that's still not a good enough reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'd assume that as a "pro C++ programmer" you would have that reason given if you decide to do so.

Answer (score 2):

> It makes it seem like it's not my code, but I am using some other person's code instead.

How would you write the `<fstream>` library? Opening files is not something that can be done in the pure C++ language. A library that provides that capability is needed. At base, opening files has to be done by the operating system and the OS exposes that to your code. The OS itself has to deal with other software that enables it to do these things.

Or what about this: Addition doesn't happen by magic, so somebody had to spell out exactly how to do it for your program to be able to do `a + b`. Does writing `a + b` make you feel like you're using other people's code, the code which describes how the add instruction is implemented on the CPU?

No single piece of software is going to do everything. Every piece of software will have to interact with other components, and virtually always some of those other components will be the results of someone else's work. You should just get used to the idea that your software has its own area of responsibility and it will rely on others to handle other things.

Comment: In other words, _"abstraction, bro"_. Quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Re-inventing the wheel is a bad idea. Especially if that wheel has been designed and built by people smarter and more knowledgeable by than you and is known to everyone else who is trying to build cars (program C++).

Use the headers; don't be daft.

Answer (score 0):

By the time one re-implements most standard routines, one might as well make a new language.  That why we has a wide selection of languages from which to choose.  Folks have dreamed-up a better idea.  Re-inventing the wheel is good - we don't drive on chariot tires much these days.

C and C++ may not be the greatest, but with 40 years of history, they do have holding power (and lots of baggage).  So if you are going to program in a language - use its resources, with its strengths and weaknesses.  Chances are far greater, your solution, will not be better than the existing libraries improved 1,000s of others.

But who knows - you code *may* be better.